# Peek previous/next cells in UICollectionView with native paging enabled?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I want a collection view to page through cells and centered, but display a portion of the previous and next cells like this:

[image]

There are tons of hacks out there, but I'd like to achieve this with the native paging property of the `UICollectionView`. Making the cell the full width of the collection view doesn't show previous/next cells, and making the cell width smaller doesn't snap to center when paging.

Is is possible to make the collection view 80% of the screen width for example, and let the previous/next cells bleed outside the bounds (no clip to bounds)?

[image]

Or any other ideas to achieve this using the native paging?

Comment: You can do it with scroll view by disabling `clipsToBounds`. This will make it draw what is out of scroll view. What needs to be done after that is override `hitTest` so it can detect touches even out of its bounds (best done on it's superview). But collection view may be a bit of a problematic due to cell dequeuing. It might be that it will work if it takes a bit of a buffer (loads/persists at least first offscreen cell in both directions) but it might also be completely strict and remove a cell as soon as it is out of the screen. Let us know if you find out the result.

Comment: Also if you are looking for a quick solution and you don't expect too many of these cells to show then the result may easily be done with a scroll view having a stack view.

Comment: I don't think there's a better way than to do this manually. I posted a code review here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/197017/page-and-center-uicollectionview-like-app-store

Comment: Actually there might be. If I understand correctly you could subclass flow layout and override a method `targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset:)`. Basically you disable paging but may compute what would the offset need to be for paging to take effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's an easy way to do this with the native paging enabled. 
But you can easily do a custom paging by utilising `scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>)` to set the destination you want. By adding some logic to that you can create the pagination.
You can find examples [here](https://medium.com/@maher.santina90/how-to-create-cells-that-peek-on-the-sides-like-ios-11-app-store-ef4bb54c0c7d) and [here](https://medium.com/@shaibalassiano/tutorial-horizontal-uicollectionview-with-paging-9421b479ee94)

Answer (score 3):

**iOS Swift 4**

Use the below two methods to meek the previous and next screens.

```
private func calculateSectionInset() -> CGFloat {
    let deviceIsIpad = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad
    let deviceOrientationIsLandscape = UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape
    let cellBodyViewIsExpended = deviceIsIpad || deviceOrientationIsLandscape
    let cellBodyWidth: CGFloat = 236 + (cellBodyViewIsExpended ? 174 : 0)
    let buttonWidth: CGFloat = 50
    let inset = (collectionFlowLayout.collectionView!.frame.width - cellBodyWidth + buttonWidth) / 4
    return inset
}

private func configureCollectionViewLayoutItemSize() {
    let inset: CGFloat = calculateSectionInset() // This inset calculation is some magic so the next and the previous cells will peek from the sides. Don't worry about it
    collectionFlowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: inset, bottom: 0, right: inset)
    collectionFlowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: collectionFlowLayout.collectionView!.frame.size.width - inset * 2, height: collectionFlowLayout.collectionView!.frame.size.height)
}
```

Don't forget to invoke `configureCollectionViewLayoutItemSize()` method in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` of your `UIViewController`.

[image: Screenshot]

For more detailed reference [Click Here](https://medium.com/@shaibalassiano/tutorial-horizontal-uicollectionview-with-paging-9421b479ee94)